# How to logout shell in dialog script?

Tags: bash, shell, dialog

I tried logout, exit, TMOUT.

If I use logout, it prompts `logout: not login shell: use 'exit'`.

If I use exit, it just exit the dialog, not the shell.

If I set TMOUT=1, TMOUT will remain no changed.

Can I logout shell in dialog script?

```
#!/bin/bash

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
OPTIONS=(1 "Logout")

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "back" \
                --title "title" \
                --menu "menu" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
        1)
            logout
            TMOUT=1
            exit
            ;;
esac
```

---

Edit 1:

This is also not working

```
//menu.sh
case $CHOICE in
        1)
            exit 99
            ;;
esac



./menu.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $? -eq 99 ]
then
    logout
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash script is executed in a subshell when you call it directly. You need to source it if you'd like to run it in the current shell.

```
source Script.sh
```

Or simply

```
. Script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script you could set the exit value (e.g. exit 99) then check for it in the way you call the script:

```
./Script.sh; if [ $? -eq 99 ] ;then exit fi
```

You can set up the terminal session to close on it's own:

```
Terminal.app > Preferences > Profiles > Shell
    - "When the shell exists:"
        > Close if the shell exited cleanly
    - "Ask before closing:"
        (•) Never
        -- OR --
        (•) Only if there are....
```

You can kill terminals from the script :

```
killall Terminal
```